# how to test mailgun sending emails with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, mailgun

My app is on rails and I send an emails to app users with different purposes - from devise notifications to any other purposes. I'm use a mailgun to send emails just like that:

```
def send_simple_message
  RestClient.post "https://api:YOUR_API_KEY"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
  :from => "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
  :to => "bar@example.com, YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
  :subject => "Hello",
  :text => "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
end
```

Emails sending and receiving works good, but I wonder, how can I test it in acceptance tests using Capybara. Capybara-email does not work at all. Any ideas?

**UPDATED**

Based on best answer, a have rebuild my sending method to use mailgun gem. Now, i can get email in rspec, by i have no idea about how to click on links in email. I tried all i can with no luck. Will be appriciated for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capybara-email probably isn’t working for you because you’re not using the Rails ActionMailer to integrate with Mailgun - Beyond that, you could be using the mailgun-ruby gem which has a test mode documented in the readme - https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/README.md#testing-mail-deliveries. If you’re not going to use that then you’ll need to mock the request using WebMock or equivalent

Comment: thanks. maybe you know, how can i click on link inside my email[:html]? for example, it contain such html: <p>Welcome !</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=rnfCm8Wiy1_CpcUVUtwx">Confirm my account</a></p>

Comment: @NickolayEfimov You would need to parse the email contents (nokogiri, etc), extract the url, and then visit the url in the current capybara session.  That's exactly what `capybara-email` does with emails sent via the ActionMailer test mailer.  In your case (since you're using the mailgun test mode) you'd need to do that with the relevant members of the emails in `Mailgun::Client.deliveries` - If you need more details open a new question with the specifics.